# How to make get route that contain special character in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i wanna submit a form using get method and then get the parameters from URL and do something with it. but i dont know how to generate my route. it keep showing error `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`
so the URL should be like this: `search/?q=something`. i want to get `something` from URL and do a data base query with it.

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('/search/?q={query}', 'MoviesController@search');
```

**MoviesController.php**

```
 public function search($query)
    {
        $this->validate($query, [
            'search' => 'required'
        ]);
        $search = Movie::where('name', 'like', '%' . $query. '%')->get();

        return view('inc.search')->with('search', $search);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/search" method="GET">
    {{-- @csrf --}}
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

i don't know my HTML part is even true or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?q={query}` You don't need that in your Route definition, as I'm pretty sure that's an invalid way of defining a Route Parameter. Replace

```
public function search($query){
  $this->validate($query, [
    'search' => 'required'
  ]);
```

with

```
public function search(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request->all(), [
    'q' => 'required'
  ]);

  $search = Movie::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input("q"). '%')->get();
```

and make sure you have `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your `MoviesController`.

Comment: yeah it works. by the way i don't need @csrf in forms that has GET method?

Comment: Correct; CSRF is only required for `POST`. Check the Middleware `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` to see the logic.